# Browse Verdaccio UI by Hostname or IP

Tags: verdaccio

I have installed Verdaccio under Ubuntu.
Packages are published and accessible.

The machine is accessible via two different aliases, as well as via IP address.

When I now open the Web UI of Verdaccio, the published packages are only displayed in the first one called (e.g. npm.xxx.com). If I then open the Web UI by calling the IP address or the other alias, the info appears that no packages have been published yet and the previously used URL (npm.xxx.com) is displayed as the registry.

I have tested both with and without reverse proxy, the behaviour is the same in both. The Proxy got all serverAlias as well as the IP adress.

The service only runs once, if it is stopped, all calls fail.

Also, there is only one config file and if you change the appearance of the web UI, this change is displayed for all calls.

How can I make it so that no matter which URL is used to call up the Web UI, the existing packages are displayed?

Cheers
Anjs

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think is not possible at this point, there were some discussions like here

https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/discussions/3474#discussion-4541243

If you open dev tools, the browser expects to serve them in a specific domain and you don't see packages because JS fails on load, independently if is right or not behavior is open t discussion, just is how it is now.

Probably there are more, I've replied to the same question a few times.  The recommendation is to use one domain at this point.